# Is there an explicit polynomial form for the product of consecutive integers?

Tags: analysis, integers

I have the product $\prod_{j=0}^{r-1} (n+j)= n(n+1)\cdots(n+r-1)$ where n is a positive integer, and I was wondering if there was an explicit polynomial form for it (as a polynomial of degree r). I've tried searching for it online, and I've found expressions for when r is even and when r is odd, resulting in polynomials with coefficients that follow the central factorial number sequence, which I know nothing about. Is there a proof/paper that discusses this explicit form, this sequence, and these coefficients? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the "[rising factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)" (also Pochhammer function, etc.)

As you've defined it, it already is a polynomial of degree $r$, and is often written $x^{(r)}$. The coefficients in terms of $n$ are not trivial to compute.

One reason these functions are interesting is that if $\Delta(f(x)) = f(x+1)-f(x),$ then $\Delta (x^{(n)}) = nx^{(n-1)},$ so the rising factorials are to $\Delta$ as $x^n$ is to $\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! How would one go about calculating the 2nd coefficient? In my particular case, we know that the 1st coefficient is 1 (multiplying n^r). But all I really need to know is the 2nd coefficient, multiplying n^(r-1). The sources I've looked at say that the coefficients follow the central factorial number sequences for r odd and even (A008955 and A008956 respectively on OEIS), but a proof was not provided.

Comment: The second coefficient is obviously the sum of $0+1+2+\dots + r-1 = r(r-1)/2$.

Comment: Why is that the case? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm failing to see it.

Comment: The coefficient of $x^{r-1}$ in the polynomial $(x+s_1)(x+s_2)\cdots(x+s_r)$ is $s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_r$. You can prove that by induction on $r$, I suppose, if you haven't seen that result.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients
are the unsigned
Stirling numbers
of the first kind:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind

From this,
the explicit formulas
for the first few
coefficients are
$\binom{n}{2},
\binom{n}{4}+2\binom{n+1}{4},
\binom{n}{6}+8\binom{n+1}{6}+6\binom{n+2}{6}
$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment
rather than an answer,
but too complicated to enter
as a comment.

If you want to
estimate the asymptotics
of
$p_n(x)
=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+j)
$
for large $x$,
these results of mine
might be useful:

Let $r = (n-1)/2,
u = x+r,
v = (p_n(x))^{1/n}$.
($u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$ and $n$.)

Then
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{u^n}{p_n(x)}
=\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{u}{v}
=1$,
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{u^n-p_n(x)}{u^{n-2}}
=\dfrac{n^3-n}{24}$,
and
$\lim_{x \to \infty} u(u-v)
=\dfrac{n^2-1}{24}$
so that
$p_n(x)
=u^n-u^{n-2}\dfrac{n^3-n}{24}+o(u^{n-2})
$
and
$(p_n(x))^{1/n}
=u-\dfrac{n^2-1}{24u}+o(\dfrac1{u})
$.